# Cannot boot XP, after installing Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, boot, grub

I had 2 partitions with 2 XP. I selected the 1st partition, formatted it, and installed Ubuntu 9.10 on it.

Now I can't boot into XP cz is showing me the XP loader of the XP that I deleted...
I tried fixmbr and fixboot but with no effect.

In the beginning XP couldn't boot, but at least I could browse the folders from Linux.
Now in the Disk Utility it's written unrecognised, unknown or unused.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Here it is:

```
~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb7e61057

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       22508   180795478+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2           22509       30400    63392490    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5   *       22752       30400    61440592+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6           22509       22751     1951834+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

    ~#
    ~# ntfsfix /dev/sda5
    Mounting volume... $MFT has invalid magic.
    ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
    Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
    Failed to startup volume: Input/output error.
    FAILED
    Attempting to correct errors... $MFT has invalid magic.
    ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
    Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
    FAILED
    Failed to startup volume: Input/output error.
    Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

**Update:** after playing with some partition boot CDs:

```
root@ubuntu-tower:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb7e61057

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       22508   180795478+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3           22752       30400    61440592+   7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Here's a screenshot of GParted and Disk Utility:

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you should've installed ubuntu on the 2nd drive instead,this way you'll be able to use them both without having to modify GRUB

Comment: when you want install ubuntu on your Sp you must choose your slave xp, I think you format you master xp os then your boot information for both of operating system was lost.

Comment: no i dont think so.. i think it has to do something with some windows loader, or loading direction to start XP from that partition.. but i dont really know how to do make it like this..

Comment: @Am1rr3zA yes it must be something like this, but there is not any way to rebuild it for the 2nd partition?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as you and [Partition Table Doctor](http://www.ptdd.com/ptdmoreinfo.htm) resolved it.
Some time ago in work when WinXP can`t load I use fixmbr and fixboot commands from WinXP recovery console and it works too, [here](http://askbobrankin.com/fix_mbr.html) is tutorial

Comment: ive tried those commands and nothing came up

Comment: so you can try Partition Table doctor, it also works for me.

Comment: i tried that program man, and nothing happened..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right: the problem seems to be due to the XP bootloader "gone with the wind". Does any of these how-to help?

- [How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader (Updated for Ubuntu 9.10)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708)
- [[HOW TO] Get back your Windows XP Bootloader](http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t292614.html)